# 'Error in call to API function \"files/list_folder\": This app is currently disabled' on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, authorization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have that message error, but I don't understand why it comes. I reinstalled a new version, and I use that code to check if it is well authorized to DropBox:

```
if (([DBClientsManager authorizedClient] && [DBClientsManager authorizedTeamClient]))
```

It says me ok, but when I send the content to my dropbox account, I have that response:

```
ErrorContent = "Error in call to API function \"files/list_folder\": This app is currently disabled.";  
RequestId = 51e8ef6340500ad7aacee5ffb32c3489;  
StatusCode = 400;  
UserMessage = nil;
```

I authorized it three days ago for information. 
But if I connect to dropbox again, with that code:

```
[DBClientsManager authorizeFromController:[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                               controller:self
                                  openURL:^(NSURL *url) {
                                      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                                  }];
```

it is ok, it works.

My question is, how can I really know if the user can send or not content to his dropbox account without asking the authorization everytime and how long expired the token?

May be the token is not valid anymore? May be he is not authorized because the time is expired?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `authorizedClient` and `authorizedTeamClient` properties only check if you have an access token stored locally. They don't indicate if that access token is still valid.

Dropbox API access tokens don't expire by themselves, but they can become invalid for a variety of reasons. For example, users and apps can explicitly revoke tokens. You can't be sure if an access token is still valid unless you attempt an API call with it. For example, you can try it by calling [`getCurrentAccount`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBUSERSUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBUSERSUserAuthRoutes(im)getCurrentAccount)

In your case, this access token was no longer valid because the app that it is for is disabled. (That is, the developer either disabled the Dropbox API app from the [Dropbox App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps), or the account that owns the app itself was disabled.)